# Report from two tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got these two tables:

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|---------------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   |BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_ApplicableTaxes | BIL_Status |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|---------------------|------------|
|    232 | 2018-03-01 |     105 |            1 |                 8,9 |    charged |
|    233 | 2018-03-01 |      30 |            2 |                   9 |  cancelled |
|    234 | 2018-03-01 |      21 |            2 |                  10 |    charged |
|    239 | 2018-03-01 |     105 |            1 |                 8,9 |    charged |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|---------------------|------------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 | Taxe de séj. |      5.000 |
|      9 |          TPS |      5.000 |
|     10 |          TVQ |     19.975 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

I would to have a report with all the taxes with they amount and this between two dates.

So something like this:

```
|--------------|------------|----------|
| STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |    taxes |
|--------------|------------|----------|
| Taxe de séj. |      5.000 |    10.50 |
|          TPS |      5.000 |    10.50 |
|          TVQ |     19.975 |     8.38 |
|--------------|------------|----------|
```

**How to:**
I need to get all the billable items from `___BillableDatas` and if the status is not `cancelled`, multiply the amount by `BIL_Quantity`. After I need to check the sales taxes id applicable to this items in the `___SalesTaxes` table. I can have sometimes more than one taxe per item (9,10).

My attempt is the following:

```
SELECT BIL_Id, BIL_Date, BIL_Rate, BIL_Quantity, BIL_ApplicableTaxes, BIL_Status, STX_Id, STX_TaxeName, STX_Amount
       , taxes 
       , BIL_Quantity*BIL_Rate/100 AS taxes
FROM  ___BillableDatas
INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes
ON ___BillableDatas.BIL_ApplicableTaxes = ___SalesTaxes.STX_Id
WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31'
AND BIL_Status != 'cancelled'
```

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3929

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow your math, so I can't give an answer, though I will say that `FIND_IN_SET` would probably be helpful here to match an `STX_Id` against the CSV list of IDs in the `BIL_ApplicableTaxes` column.  But, in general, you should not store CSV in your tables.

Comment: For math, I need to get BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity first. The total should be compared to the applicable taxes in ___SalesTaxes.

Comment: I changed your database schema because it's better to have an intermediate table. Many to Many Relationships need multiple instances on both sides of the relationship. [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fe9e). But like @TimBiegeleisen was saying, I don't know which math you're making to have the taxes results. So it's difficult to construct a SELECT query.